# Route to methods in the controller in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How can I point to different methods in a controller without writing in Routes.php file. So, I have a controller.

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('front.home.index');
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return view('front.home.business');
    }

    public function aboutus()
    {
        return view('front.home.about');
    }
```

This controller can have unlimited methods and I want to call these methods without writing each method in the routes file. e.g. How can I call home/business or home/aboutus without writing in Routes.php. Currently I am doing like this.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home/business', 'HomeController@business');
Route::get('/home/aboutus', 'HomeController@aboutus');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change names of methods in your controller this way:

```
index => getIndex
business => getBusiness
aboutus => getAboutus
```

You can then use:

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

Reference: [Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Comment: This works. You saved my time. Thanks a lot :) I am not able to upvote because I don't have 15 reputations. I'll surely do it once I get them.